# Colocar fecha local en una carpeta

Tags: windows

**Buen día**, sería alguien amable en poder enseñarme cómo puedo crear una carpeta y que además tenga puesta la hora local a través del cmd

Comment: Que has intentado al momento?, Considera que tú pregunta puede terminar cerrada pues no muestras ningún avance

Comment: no se trata de ningun lenguaje o problema de código, quizás deberías mirar en otros sitios de StackExchange

Answer (score 2):

Para crear directorios desde la terminal ***(CMD)*** se debe utilizar el comando `md` o `mkdir` como en ***Linux***. Por ejemplo para crear un directorio llamador `StackOverflow` es posible escribir.

```
MD StackOverflow
```

A continuación si ingresar el comandor ***DIR*** el cual sirve para listar los directorios verás que la carpeta `StackOverflow` fue creada correctamente con la fecha de creación.

Ahora si deseas crear otro directorio en la carpeta StackOverflow simplemente debes ingresar por consola.

```
MD StackOverflow\dirPrueba
```

Ahora para validar la creación de esta nueva carpeda debes ingresar:

```
DIR StackOverflow
```

Ahora bien

Es probable que el problema resida en el interprete de comandos.

El formato `%date:~0,2%` significa que se posicione en el primer carater y extraiga 2. Ejemplo para `DATE = 25.12.1986`

```
set aa=%date:~6,2%
set mm=%date:~3,2%
set dd=%date:~0,2%

echo %dd% - %mm% - %aa%

25 - 12 - 1986
```

El unico problema de que este en ingles es el fomato de la fecha :

```
DD/MM/AAAA o MM/DD/AAAA
```

El formato de la fecha es configurable desde el panel de control e independiente del idiomma.

Espero sea lo que estés buscando. Saludos!

Answer (score -1):

Para crear una carpeta a través de la linea de comando debes utilizar el comando mkdir.  Para obtener la fecha puedes usar la variable %TIME%.  El problema que tienen acá es que la hora es, por ejemplo, "12:18", y no se pueden crear archivos o carpeta con ":" en el nombre.  Para evitar esto puedes reemplazarlo con un guión.
Todo esto se puede hacer con esta linea:

```
mkdir %TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%
```

De esta manera te va a crear una carpeta con la hora actual como nombre, y usando un guión, por ejemplo: "12-18".
Los parámetros después del ":" son para tomar sólo una parte del string de la hora.
Suerte!

Answer (score -1):

En cmd podés crear carpetas con la instrucción **mkdir** y le indicas la ruta, ejemplo:

```
mkdir c:\test
```

Si querés crearla con el nombre de la fecha y hora local, podes hacerlo obteniendo la fecha y hora del sistema con **date** y **time** pero quitando los caracteres especiales, por ejemplo:

```
mkdir %date:~5,2%-%date:~8,2%-%date:~11,4%" "%time:~0,2%" "%time:~3,2%" "%time:~6,2%
```

Te va a crear una carpeta con el siguiente formato: 17-02-2020 12 52 39

Saludos.